# Mock an internal function call of current class under test

Tags: php, phpunit, php-5.3

I want to test this function:

```
public function reset()
{
    if(!$this->onBeforeReset())      // Protected, internal method
    {
         return false;
    }

    // Continue with tests
}
```

I'd wish to test it when `onBeforeReset` function return false or true, too.
How can I do that? Is that possible?
Is there a way to "mock" some parts of the class under test?

Comment: you are testing if the return value is true/false. what do you mean by you wish to test the same?

Comment: I want to test the `reset` function when the `onBeforeReset` return true and when `onBeforeReset` returns false.

Comment: If there are possibilities that `//continue with tests` part of the code return false, you may want to return an array with a key (['onBeforeReset'] for example) for the return value of onBeforeReset() and another for reset(). Finally you can test if that particular key exists/set... .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, unless the method you want to mock is private or final you can mock just this one method. An example:

```
$sut = $this->getMock('Your\Class', array('onBeforeReset'));
```

The second argument of `getMock` method is array contains methods that phpunit will mock. If this array is empty phpunit will mock all methods from the object, but if you precise at least one method phpunit will mock only methodz you pass into this array.

And you mock method as usual:

```
$sut->expects($this->any())
    ->method('onBeforeReset')
    ->will($this->returnValue(true));
```

And finally you can test the method you want to test:

```
$this->assertWhatever($expectedValue, $sut->reset());
```

Comment: mhm... it's interesting. I already use mocks, but I didn't think about mocking a part of the current test. However, my object is returned using `getInstance` factory method, any advice on that?

Comment: you always can mock "getInstance" to return your $sut. But definitly better way is to build the object directly. But pay attention for one more thing - your protected method "onBeforeReset" should be tested as well! And private/protected methods should be tested through public interface, so maybe actually you don't want mock "reset" method at all? Think about it :)

Answer (score 0):

How I understand unittesting, is you test the public interfaces of your classes. So in your example, you only assert the result of reset(), and not all the protected and private functions called inside. You then deduce what result onBeforeReset() gave from the result reset() gave.

This is of course not a 100% rule. Sometimes you really want to test a private or protected method, for whatever reason (do however consider that this might mean you actually should refactor your code).

The creator of PHPUnit has written some thoughts and given some examples (http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/881-Testing-Your-Privates.html). Basically you use Reflection to make private and protected methods and properties publicly accesible.